# Nuxt 3 App > Express API Server CORS error (on same host)

Tags: node.js, nuxtjs3

I have a simple SSR Nuxt 3 app that I'm trying to get to talk to an Express app running on the same machine and I'm getting a CORS error that I can't figure out how to resolve:

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8081/api/test' from origin 'http://147.182.204.161:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

The Nuxt app is running on port 8080 and the Express app is running on port 8081

The Nuxt app makes a simple GET request to the Express app like so:

```
const response = await $fetch('http://localhost:8081/api/test')
console.log('response:', response);
```

This works fine when running locally, but as soon as I put it on a VPS I get a CORS error. The Nuxt app is running via the 'built in' Node server or whatever default server Nuxt 3 comes with via:

`PORT=8080 node .output/server/index.mjs`

My understanding is this is [the recommended way to run a Nuxt3 app in production.](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/guide/deploy/node-server)

I also get the error if I use a fully qualified domain name e.g. http://example.com

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8081/api/test' from origin 'http://example.com:8080' has been blocked by CORS policy: The request client is not a secure context and the resource is in more-private address space `local`.
```

Also I get this error **regardless of whether the Express app is running** so it can't be a CORS issue w/ the Express app (I tried fully open CORS on the Express app and it made no difference) so I suspect the issue is related to the browser?

Comment: I wonder if it could be a CORS error on the basis that the browser cannot successfully perform an automatic OPTIONS call prior to the cross-site operation?

Answer (score 1):

Add `server/middleware/cors.ts`

with content:

```
import { defineEventHandler, setResponseHeaders } from 'h3'

export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  setResponseHeaders(event, {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
    'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials': 'true',
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": '*',
    "Access-Control-Expose-Headers": '*'
  })
})
```

to check see on headers, eg:

```
http -h GET http://localhost:3000/
```

by default gives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
connection: close
content-length: 20459
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 19 Nov 2022 09:44:28 GMT
server-timing: -;dur=0;desc="Generate"
x-powered-by: Nuxt
```

but with this middleware you will see

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
access-control-allow-credentials: true
access-control-allow-headers: *
access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: *
connection: close
content-length: 20459
content-type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
date: Sat, 19 Nov 2022 09:45:00 GMT
server-timing: -;dur=0;desc="Generate"
x-powered-by: Nuxt
```

connected issue:

https://github.com/nuxt/framework/issues/6650

but you do not need return nothing in this middleware, because nuxt correctly handle options requests for you.

Comment: as far as I understand this should work but at least it didn't for me